# react-native onPress() toggles automatically on a loop component rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native-base

I'm looping through a **native-base** `<Card dataArray={data} />` component rendering some components with Buttons. It was working alright (*Listed all components as expected*) but I soon added an `onPress` event to the Button and got an automatic `onPress` bug, weird enough it runs (*clicks hence runs the bounded function*) only once while components suppose to render with those buttons are many.

```js
//- Inside constructor I bind testLogs
this.testLogs = this.testLogs(this);

//- Outside render...
testLogs(value) {
  console.log(value);
}

//- Inside return of render()

<Card dataArray={devices}
  renderRow={(theme) => 
    <CardItem>
      {(theme.picture) ? 
        <Thumbnail size={100} source={theme.picture} />:
        <Thumbnail size={100} source={defaultImage} />
      }
      <Text style={{fontSize: 16}}> {theme.name} </Text>
      <Button primary style={{marginRight: 10}}> Command </Button>
      <Button success onPress={this.testLogs} > Edit </Button>
    </CardItem>
  }>
</Card>
```

I should also say all the rendered components don't run the `onPress={this.testLogs}` bound function when i click them after they render.

What could be triggering this? Or is loop rendering not the best approach to this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use onPress={this.testlogs.bind(this)}

Comment: Ooh man, this worked!
I'm getting lots of output though, but it works!
Thanks.